# Does iOS 9.0.2 stop autorotating?

Tags: ios, ios9, landscape, autorotate

I'm running the app I'm developing in an `iOS 8` device and it rotates to landscape, but not in a device I've just updated to `iOS 9.0.2`, is somebody else experiencing this?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Just tried in `iOS 9.0` simulator and autorotation neither works... is there something additional to take into account for autorotation in `iOS 9`?

Comment: Yes it's not working on my side too

Comment: I just turned off and on the device. Now it's working fine.

Comment: @IdreesAshraf it seems not to be the problem in my case... I've also tested in `iOS 9.0` simulator and it neither rotates...

Comment: It seemed to be a know bug for iPad Air 2. This thread has details on it: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7489

Comment: Interesting. Works fine here; even on the simulator. I'll check on 9.0.2 though (Running 9.0.1 )

Comment: @Abhinav I'm testing on iPhone (iPhone 5, exactly)

Comment: Hmmm, for me it works fine on iPhone 6.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the device several times as well as Xcode and now it seems to work...